# DataFrame does not allow Timestamps conversion for resampling

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I have a 12 millions entries csv file that I imported as dataframe with pandas that looks like this.

```
pair    time    open    close
0   AUD/JPY 20170102 00:00:08.238   83.774002   84.626999
1   AUD/JPY 20170102 00:00:08.352   83.774002   84.626999
2   AUD/JPY 20170102 00:00:13.662   84.184998   84.324997
3   AUD/JPY 20170102 00:00:13.783   84.184998   84.324997
```

The time column is a string but I need a datetime object in order to downsample the dataframe and get OHLC values. The df.resample function requires datetime-like index (DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex). I tried

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

but this creates Timestamp, and for some reason I cannot convert the Timestamps into datetime object.

```
time = df['time'].dt.to_pydatetime()
df['time'] = time
```

This works creating a separate array and assigning the resulting list but as soon as I incorporate it into the dataframe it is converted back into Timestamps automatically. It does not work even creating a new dataframe with dtype = 'object' and then adding the datetime list as before.

A way around would be that of converting each row individually but given the size of the dataframe it would take ages. Any suggestions?

EDIT: with

```
time = pd.DataFrame(dtype = 'datetime64')
time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
time = time.dt.to_pydatetime()
new = pd.DataFrame({'pair': df['pair'],'time': pd.Series(time, dtype='object'), 'open': df['open'], 'close': df['close']}, dtype ='object')
```

I am now able to receive a datetime object when calling new['time'][0], however

```
new['time'].resample('5T')
```

still raises the error: "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'"

EDIT: Ok, so apparently I just had to set the timestamp as index of the dataframe and then resample applies without issues.

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
import datetime as dt
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%y/%m/%d")
df['timeconvert'] = df['time'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently I just had to set the timestamp as index of the dataframe and then resample applies without issues. There is no need to bother with timestamp conversion or anything else, thanks anyway for the reply.